# libclang: get a collection of method locations

Tags: parsing, clang

I'm interested on clang to parse C/C++ code and be able to locate methods and functions.

Is it possible to use clang to parse a C++ source code file and get a collection of classes and methods and where they're located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a clang plugin, which does this for you.

Take a look at [this article](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/WritingClangPlugins). It basically describes how to build your own plugin and use the ASTConsumer to traverse the AST. Like it is written in the article, start from the existing plugin example [PrintFunctionNames](http://www.llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/PrintFunctionNames/). The method `HandleTopLevelDecl(DeclGroupRef DG)` is invoked for each function declaration. Additionally to `ND->getNameAsString()` you could call `ND->getLocation()` in this method. Also have a look at the [API documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html) and this two questions for more information:

[How to get location of variable name in clang::VarDecl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054729/how-to-get-location-of-variable-name-in-clangvardecl)

[Handle C++ functions with clang API to insert code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602967/handle-c-functions-with-clang-api-to-insert-code)